# data base oracle foreign key error ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: oracle

while making foreign key in player table it shows following error

> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

```
create table person
(

per_ssn number(10) not null,

per_name varchar2(30) not null,

CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (per_ssn,per_name)

); 


create table Player 
(

player_ssn number(10) not null,

player_name varchar2(30) not null,

football_club_name varchar2(30) not null, 

p_age number(2) not null,

p_weight number(3) not null,

p_height number(10) not null,

country varchar2(20) not null,

p_starting_date date not null, 

p_ending_date date not null

);

alter table Player

 add constraint player_ssn 

 FOREIGN KEY (player_ssn)

 REFERENCING person (per_ssn)on delete cascade
```

I want to make two primary keys in person table and then want to refer these
primary keys in player table.

If I make one primary key and then refer it in player table, then it does not show error but I want to make two primary keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be referencing `per_ssn,per_name` because that is your PK on `person`.
Anyway, think about making `per_ssn` your PK in `person` table

```
alter table Player
add constraint player_ssn 
FOREIGN KEY (player_ssn,player_name)
REFERENCING person (per_ssn,per_name)on delete cascade
```

Comment: yes i have tried and made only one primary  per_ssn in person and then refer it to player table and it works but i want to make both the attributes of person primary key and then want to refer it to player table

Comment: @Umer.farooq6028Farooq If what makes a person unique is person_ssn and per_name do as I posted. If any of those attributes make a person unique (I doubt per_name is unique) make per_ssn your pk and an unique index on per_name

Comment: yes you are right and now i'm doing the same thing but is there any possibility in oracle that we can reference both primary keys of a table

Comment: @Umer.farooq6028Farooq If you want you could create a PK and an unique constraint on person and make 2 FK on Player (I don't really see the point on that):
`create table person
(

per_ssn number(10) not null,

per_name varchar2(30) not null,

CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (per_ssn),
CONSTRAINT uq_PersonName UNIQUE  (per_name)
)`

`alter table Player
add constraint player_name
FOREIGN KEY (player_name)
REFERENCING person (per_name)on delete cascade

alter table Player
add constraint player_ssn 
FOREIGN KEY (player_ssn)
REFERENCING person (per_ssn)on delete cascade'`